# Max number in a column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I haven't been able to find an answer to this because I don't know how to word the search terms. **How do I prevent a cell from going above the number 300,000**? It is simply the sum of one column subtracted by another but when I haven't completed a set (because I am not to that day yet) it places a result higher than 300,000 and can be confusing.

Comment: do you have any formula in that cell?

Comment: Yes, it's just this: =E4-B4

Comment: E4 currently has the number 500,000 in it and B4 is empty as now. Is it possible to to show an answer not greater than 300,000 until I enter data in B4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## solution 1:

```
=IF(E4-B4<300000; E4-B4; )
```

## solution 2:

```
=IF(AND(E4<>""; B4<>""); E4-B4; )
```

Comment: Solution 2 works. Thank you! Very much